# custom link in top header shows wrong url

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added custom link in my local.xml in "top.links"

```
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
      <label>Shipping Estimator</label>
                <url>shipping-estimator</url>
                <title>Shipping Estimator</title>
                <prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>5</position>
            </action>
</reference>
```

Link is added in top header but on some page e.g checkout page it is shown like

```
/checkout/onepage/shipping-estimator
```

Am i missing some parameter above ? or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<action method="addLink" block="top.links" translate="label title">
    <label>Shipping Estimator</label>
    <url>shipping-estimator</url>
    <title>Shipping Estimator</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare>
    <urlParams />
    <position>5</position>
</action>
```

You basically need to set the node `prepare` to true. To see what's happening behind the scenes, refer to https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.2/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php#L85